# trigger angular.ui popover on event but on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

is it possible to trigger the [popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) directive on an event? I'm trying to look for a string character and trigger a custom template, however, I cannot find a way to get my way around it, I only see custom attributes attached to a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `popover-is-open` to display the popover on a given event.

Here is an example, where a timeout is used to simulate an event that shows the popover:

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl as vm">
    Wait for 3 seconds for the event to happen...
    <div uib-popover="Read the message!"
         popover-title="Hello World!"
         popover-placement="bottom"
         id="popover"
         class="btn btn-default spaced"
         popover-is-open="vm.showPopover">
        Popover
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function PopoverDemoCtrl($timeout) {
    var popoverDemoCtrl = this;

    popoverDemoCtrl.showPopover = false;
    $timeout(function () {
        popoverDemoCtrl.showPopover = true;
    }, 3000);
}

PopoverDemoCtrl.$inject = ['$timeout'];

angular
    .module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', PopoverDemoCtrl);
```

The full Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/gtgqof2k/